# Removing same name layers from layer table in JMapframe in geotool?

Tags: postgresql, java, geotools

I am making a geotool application in which I read the data from postgresql database. In this application if i make a buffer on a selected polygon then a buffer is created and buffer layer shown in layer table of JMapFrame. After that i make another buffer on another polygon then there are two layers with same name shown in the layer table in JMapFrame and both the layers shows the buffer on last selected polygon. How can I replace the same name layer with the new one from the layer table in JMapFrame.

My code runs on the click of "Buffer" Button

[image]

And Result on Jmapfrmae

[image]

In this JMapFrame all the khasra_buffer layers are the same i.e. the current buffer which is created at Id 80, Thus replacing previously created two buffers.

I want that old khasra_buffer layer should be removed and the only buffer layer that should be shown is of the current buffer on JMapframe.

Comment: In future please paste actual code in to the question instead of a picture of it.

Answer (score 1):

Since you replace the PostGIS table each time you create a buffer you shouldn't need to add a new layer each time, simply refreshing the map should generate a new view of the data. You may run into issues with the map context caching the extent of the layer if your buffer moves about.

So if you decide you need to create a new layer each time the trick is to simply remove the existing buffer layer before you add the new one. Usually you would do this by keeping a note of what the layer is and calling `mapContent.remove(layer)`. I would remove bufferedLayer outside the action method and then call remove before I create and add the new layer.

Finally for more efficiency and easy of use I would simply call the JTS `buffer` method on a selected geometry in memory and simply add that new geometry to an existing layer. I have written an [updatable layer](https://gitlab.com/snippets/22341) that you could extend to allow you to remove features as well as add them.